# Unable to display values in Dialogflow

Tags: javascript, dialogflow-es

I have an issue displaying an integer input in my DialogFlow agent. The agent runs, but instead of showing the integer value as I expect it to, it is showing the name of the variable I want to display.

[Here is the code for the fulfillment part of my agent. The red box highlighted is the value that should be displaying but it's not.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmUfP.jpg)

[Here is what you see when I run my agent on the console. As you can see, it's not displaying the value.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96fhp.jpg)

[Here is my intent for the "guidedtour_MMOTW" as it is configured in Dialogflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkNgE.jpg)

Why isn't it printing the value?

Comment: Are these 3 separate errors you are having?

Comment: These are all under 1 error: unable to display the value (which is the noOfpeoples)

Comment: Posting screen shots of code is usually pretty unhelpful. If you're going to post a screen shot, please also include the code itself in the question

Comment: Point taken with thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a double-quoted string and attempting to use a variable inside it. This is not how JavaScript does it.

The most recent versions of JavaScript support the backtick

```
`
```

as the way to create a string where some contents might be interpolated, and inside the string anything inside `${}` is what is interpolated.

So your line should be written as something line

```
agent.add(`I would assume that the ${noOfPeoples} of the...`);
```